# Empty ajax return with server side datatables

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I am facing with a problem with server side script. The count of the rows are correct but the data is empty. There was an error also that the values cannot empty or NULL.

I have added defaultContent to the columns in the script with the message `Not set` and now the rows are correct but i have only the `Not set` notification.
I tried to add the UTF-8 Charset but still not working.

**JS for the server-side:**

```
var DatatablesDataSourceAjaxServer= {
init:function() {
    $("#m_table_1").DataTable( {
        responsive:true, 
        searchDelay:500, 
        processing:true, 
        serverSide:true, 
        ajax:"assets/data/scripts/data-user-table.php", 
        columns:[ {
            data: "name",
            //defaultContent: "<i>Not set</i>"
        }
        , {
            data: "mail",
            defaultContent: "<i>Not set</i>"
        }
        , {
            data: "status",
            defaultContent: "<i>Not set</i>"
        }
        , {
            data: "role",
            defaultContent: "<i>Not set</i>"
        }
        , {
            data: "created",
            defaultContent: "<i>Not set</i>"
        }
        , {
            data: "login",
            defaultContent: "<i>Not set</i>"
        }
        , {

            data: "Actions"
        }
        ], columnDefs:[ {
            targets:-1, 
            title:"Actions", orderable:!1, render:function(a, e, t, n) {
                return'\n    <a href="" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-brand m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" title="View or edit account">\n   <i class="la la-edit"></i>\n   </a> <a href="#" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-brand m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" title="Cancel account">\n   <i class="la la-trash"></i>\n   </a>'
            }
        }
        , {
            targets:2, render:function(a, e, t, n) {
                var s= {
                    1: {
                        title: "Pending", class: "m-badge--brand"
                    }
                    , 2: {
                        title: "Delivered", class: " m-badge--metal"
                    }
                    , 3: {
                        title: "Canceled", class: " m-badge--primary"
                    }
                    , 4: {
                        title: "Success", class: " m-badge--success"
                    }
                    , 5: {
                        title: "Info", class: " m-badge--info"
                    }
                    , 6: {
                        title: "Danger", class: " m-badge--danger"
                    }
                    , 7: {
                        title: "Warning", class: " m-badge--warning"
                    }
                }
                ;
                return void 0===s[a]?a:'<span class="m-badge '+s[a].class+' m-badge--wide">'+s[a].title+"</span>"
            }
        }
        , {
            targets:3, render:function(a, e, t, n) {
                var s= {
                    1: {
                        title: "Online", state: "danger"
                    }
                    , 2: {
                        title: "Retail", state: "primary"
                    }
                    , 3: {
                        title: "Direct", state: "accent"
                    }
                }
                ;
                return void 0===s[a]?a:'<span class="m-badge m-badge--'+s[a].state+' m-badge--dot"></span>&nbsp;<span class="m--font-bold m--font-'+s[a].state+'">'+s[a].title+"</span>"
            }
        }
        ]
    }
    )
}
}

;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    DatatablesDataSourceAjaxServer.init()
}

);
```

And the data-user-table.php:

```
<?php


// DB table to use
$table = 'users';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'uid';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'name', 'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'mail',  'dt' => 1 ),
array( 'db' => 'status',   'dt' => 2 ),
array( 'db' => 'role',     'dt' => 3 ),
array(
    'db'        => 'created',
    'dt'        => 4,
    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
        return date( 'jS M y', strtotime($d));
    }
),
array(
    'db'        => 'login',
    'dt'        => 5,
    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
        return '$'.number_format($d);
    }
)
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
'user' => '',
'pass' => '',
'db'   => '',
'host' => '',
'charset' => 'utf8'
);


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar using ajax with php but dont you need a 'success:...' section for the return of the call and where you put your code that will do something on the return (including reading the data)?    This might be off track, if it is, apologies.

Comment: Yes, normally it is true, but in the example i found on DataTables it is not necessery to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you have special characters in your database (e.g. 'ø'), search `ssp.class.php` for this line:

```
"mysql:host={$sql_details['host']};dbname={$sql_details['db']}",
```

...and replace it with:

```
"mysql:host={$sql_details['host']};dbname={$sql_details['db']};charset=UTF8",
```

Credit for the solution to https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/47358/ssp-class-php-especial-characters-problem-solution

Note: In my case, my table functioned correctly in my local test environment without adding `;charset=UTF8"`. I don't know why.